# Two login screens or one with restricted permissions?

Tags: django, authentication, admin

I need this login screen http://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/ to the client (user)
and standard Admin screen for the back-office (manager or director, for example).

The first screen, which is for the client (user) allows it to choose and buy your products on the site,
and the second is the normal Admin.

Question: I use two screens login or one with restricted permissions?

How would these permissions? Remember that the client (user) can not enter the Admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking how to create a login form?  Or how to restrict access to admin pages for regular clients?

If you want to create you own login form then use the built-in [authentication views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views) from `django.contrib.auth`.

Restricting admin access is simple - if you register the user with `is_staff` property set to `False` then he/she will not able to use admin.

Comment: Got it, I think that restrict access to the second tip you gave addresses.